# Crazy behaviour of PDO when executing with LIKE statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got code something like that:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE user LIKE :user');
```

and later I got

```
$stmt->bindValue(':user', '%'.$user.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

And it do not work. I am pretty sure that this is correct way to do a LIKE statement with MySQL, but It not works when I enter some part of username, but when I enter full username it goes like a charm.
Any ideas why LIKE statement don't want to do a simple regex?

Comment: It is the correct way. Make sure you have PDO set to throw PDOExceptions on errors `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: When I bind part of username the result is empty, but when I bind whole username it works. And I want to do it in such way that when I bind part of username it will also produce some result.
And I have also set to throw exceptions. PDO thinks that it works correctly.

Comment: is there a way to check query after binding? Ignore that. I remembered that data is sent separatly do SQL...

Comment: Yeah. I just didn't got the answers :)

Comment: I can be a isseu that I use TEXT as a data type for that field?

Comment: What? You have what appears to be a username field of data type `TEXT`? Why? That should be [`CHAR` or `VARCHAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html).

Comment: hmm. Why TEXT? cause why not? don't really know why it is a TEXT. In that field there can be a company name (so no limitation on char number is allowed (my client insists on that)). Another thing is that full text search should be also for TEXT.

Comment: When I do that query in mysql workbench it produce correct result, so it should not take effect if it is TEXT, or VARCHAR, or CHAR.

Comment: Next thing that I observed. On my dev server there is no such crazy behaviour. Everything is going well, but on deployment server there is no full text search. Tables have InnoDB engine on both servers.

Comment: OK. I resolved this on my own. Problem was that, the query was wrong. I have query in a variable with and some parts of query were added when they were needed, and on end of query was added 'user = :user'. And causer query was very long in end I didn't seen that... If some one want, tu publish this answer I will accept it.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I use in my own code for LIKE queries is:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE user LIKE CONCAT(\'%\', :user, \'%\')');

$stmt->bindValue(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

using the `CONCAT` force MySQL to generate the comparison string after the $user variable has been escaped by PDO.